# Cosine Similarity Matrix for 2d array

Tags: python, dataframe, cluster-computing, data-mining

Suppose I have these data points and I want to construct a similarity graph using cosine similarity in Python. Is there a builtin function doing that? I went through many websites and posts but I couldn't find what I need. Thank you!

---

|x      |      y|

1. 1.6382 1.3781,
2. 1.2101  2.6148,
3. 2.7966  2.1787,
4. 1.3160  1.7175
5. 1.3063  1.7038,

Answer (score 1):

You can use a numpy array to store these matrices

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array( [1.6382, 1.3781, 1.2101, 2.6148, 2.7966, 2.1787, 1.3160, 1.7175, 1.3063, 1.7038]).reshape(5,2)
>>> for matrix in arr1:
    print(matrix)
```

output is -

```
[1.6382 1.3781]
[1.2101 2.6148]
[2.7966 2.1787]
[1.316  1.7175]
[1.3063 1.7038]
```

If you want to find the cosine similarity then you have to do (1 - cosineDistance). For example for `arr1[0]` and `arr1[1]` element -

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import cosine
>>> print (f" Cosine distance : {cosine(arr1[0], arr1[1])}" )
>>> print (f" Cosine similarity : {1 - cosine(arr1[0], arr1[1])}" )
```

output is -

```
Cosine distance : 0.09438929737323964
Cosine similarity : 0.9056107026267604
```